# Macro to compare two columns with colour and get the data of the column which has Amber colour

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values in two columns AA and AB columns which are filled with different colors, my formula should compare AA and AB column and find out which column have the Amber color and display the values of that column in J column

I have tried to extract the value from AB and update it in the J column using excel formula but not able to build the macro, I am trying to compare AA and AB column with color and based on that extract the values.

```
=INDEX($1:$1048576,I11,28)
```

Comment: I cannot decide why to close the question: Duplicate, too broad or unclear what you're asking. All reasons fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strValue As String

    'With statement refer to Sheet1. Change if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find Last row of column AA in Sheet1
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop starting from row 1 to LastRow variale. Change Starting position if needed
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Check interior color. You may need to change RGB
            If .Range("AA" & i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 190, 0) Then
                .Range("J" & i).Value = .Range("AA" & i).Value
            Else
                .Range("J" & i).Value = .Range("AB" & i).Value
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Error 1004: Why do you answer a question when the OP has issued the exact same question already and even accepted the answer?

Comment: @FunThomas honestly i did not read the comments or the votes to close the question. i have vote too. shall i delete the answer?

Comment: I don't mind...

Comment: It is very useful, Thanks